# Lucene query on @indexedEmbedded objects id

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Im trying to use a org.apache.lucene.search.Query to fetch all entries with a Object @indexedEmbedded with a certain @id id. This simply does not work with my current code. My code as follows:

**The Search**

```
FullTextSession fullTextSession = getFullTextSession();
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Request.class).get();

org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = queryBuilder.keyword()
                .onField("keyword.id")
                .matching(keywordId)
                .createQuery();

FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession
                .createFullTextQuery(query, Request.class);

return fullTextQuery.list();
```

**Request.class**

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Request etc etc..

    @ManyToOne
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Keyword keyword;
```

**Keyword.class**

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Keyword etc etc..

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
```

I don't receive any errors when executing this code, the result just isn't restricted to the Request objects with a keyword with the supplied id.

I use this in junction with a org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery later on, but even when trying this itself it doesn't work. I'm aware that this might be the wrong approach so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You say the results aren't restricted to the Request objects with a keyword with the supplied ID, do you mean that other request objects (those without a keyword with the supplied ID) are coming back?  Have you tried the query in Luke?

Comment: when i preform this query i receive all the entities in the table, this restriction affected nothing. I have not, could you use that with BooleanQuery or should i try a different approach?

Comment: I would just try the query `keyword.id:<your-id-here>`.

Comment: This with the queryBuilder or do i use another mean of initialization?

Comment: This would be with the tool [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/).  It's an invaluable tool to check Lucene operations.

Comment: When debugging i can see that the query string looks like this keyword.id:1 in my test case. It seems that something else is off since the query looks correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked to see what the query you just gave returns in Luke?  If it's returning something different than your code, then that will help debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indexing properties was not set properly, the index of the request class was simply not indexed as it should have been. Added following code to fix the misstake:

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        ...
        <prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">/var/lucene/indexes</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.search.lucene_version">LUCENE_CURRENT</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

Comment: This does not resolve my problem, same as yours. Are you sure you did not set anything alse?

Comment: From what I remember regarding this issue, adding the properties resolved my issues. However this was some time ago and I have not worked with lucene since. Though the tool Luke as linked in @RandomMooCow s comment helped a lot in debugging, perhaps you could give that a go. Unfortunately I can't be of much help further than that.

Comment: I found the solution, it was the attribute depth. Thanks anyway for your response!

Comment: I am having the same exact issue. Everything works fine but not querying by Id of `@IndexedEmbedded` entity (child entity). Any help here? Also I noticed that, every time a single SQL query is triggered when querying on `@IndexedEmbedded` entity. Is this correct behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a long time since this question was asked, but if anyone lands here for this same issue, here is the working solution for it -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58499826/3709922