# How to index a inherited field in Hibernate-search?

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

I am working in a java jpa Hibernate-search application, I know Hibernate-search index automatically every @Id annotation in an entity. The problem is that I have a "master domain" class with contains the @Id annotation, and then I have another class with inherit "master domain", then seems to be the Hibernate search is not recognizing the @Id field inherited.

this is my master domain class.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class MasterDomain<Key extends Object> implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;
}
```

I have a class "Language" which inherits this class:

```
@Indexed
@Entity
public class Language extends MasterDomain<Long>{

    @Field
    private String name;
}
```

Finally I have another class called "LanguageRelation" which is related with Language class. It looks like:

```
@Indexed
@Entity
public class LanguageRelation extends MasterDomain<Long>{

   @IndexedEmbedded
   private Language language;
}
```

So, when I build a lucene query to search LanguageRelation entities, I am able to search by language names like this:

```
queryBuilder.keyword().onField("language.name").matching(languageName).createQuery()
```

But I am not able to search by language id, like this:

```
queryBuilder.keyword().onField("language.id").matching(languageId).createQuery()
```

Previous query returns 0 results, as you can see, it seems to be Hibernate search is not recognizing the @Id inherited from MasterDomain, any suggestion?

**UPDATE 1 =>**
I forgot to tell MasterDomain class is in separated module from which I am trying to execute the Lucene Query. Maybe this could get into the problem?

**UPDATE 2**
This is the full code of how I am trying to build my Lucene query.

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager
                = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
                .buildQueryBuilder()
                .forEntity(LanguageRelation.class)
                .get();

Long languageId = 29L;
org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = queryBuilder.keyword().onField("language.id").matching(languageId).createQuery();

org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery fullTextQuery
                = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, LanguageRelation.class);
List<LanguageRelation> resultList = fullTextQuery.getResultList();
```

Comment: Did you try to declare "private Key id;" as protected instead of private?

Comment: As far as I know this should work correctly. Which version of Hibernate Search are you using? What is the type of the `languageId` variable in your query code?

Comment: @Stefania I changed the id modifier to "protected", but the result is the same, I forgot to specify I have all access methods for the properties.

Comment: @yrodiere languageId is Long type, I am using version 5.11.2.Final. The behavior is very strange, I suppose it is due to I am inheriting from an abstract class?, Or maybe I need to put another annotation over "Id" property?

Comment: The most likely explanation is that a query of the wrong type is generated. Please add the full code of your query, including how you create the queryBuilder in particular.

Comment: @yrodiere please check the UPDATE 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is simply that the ID isn't embedded by default.

Try replacing this:

```
@IndexedEmbedded
```

With this:

```
@IndexedEmbedded(includeEmbeddedObjectId = true)
```

Then reindex your data, and run your query again.

Comment: This saved my day. I haven't found this tweak anywhere. Thanks :) But one more doubt, Every time I query on `@IndexedEmbedded` entity's ID, single SQL query is triggered. Is this correct behaviour? I checked indexes using Luke, and they look OK.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I query on @IndexedEmbedded entity's ID". Maybe a new question with some code is in order?

Comment: I mean, I understand it as "I apply a predicate on the ID", but that has nothing to do with SQL queries, so you probably mean something else. Yeah, a code example a the logs would help.